# Problem using Google Cloud Storage library

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I am running following code in Node.js app:

```
var GoogleCloudStorage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
 var storage =  GoogleCloudStorage({
   projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
   keyFilename: 'keyfile.json'
 });
```

It is showing this error
`GoogleCloudStorage is not a function`
What is the mistake?

Comment: `const GoogleCloudStorage = require('@google-cloud/storage');` Note the `const` and not `var`. Note, I dont' recommend using the spelling `GoogleCloudStorage` as this has meaning (classes). instead just use `storage` or `googleStorage` or `storageClient`.

Comment: still throwing same error!

Comment: Have you installled the Google Cloud Storage SDK for node?

Comment: i ran npm install --save @google-cloud/storage . is there something else to be installed?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage#installing-the-client-library

Comment: i have already installed this module

Comment: Something is not setup correctly on your system or your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage =  new Storage({
   projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
   keyFilename: 'keyfile.json'
 });
```

I could not get the nodejs compiler to accept `GoogleCloudStorage`.